# Can a school monitor my school laptop?

Tags: network

So i'm on my school computer right now at home, and I was wondering, if i'm at home on my internet connection, can my school use their monitoring app (DyKnow) and see what i'm doing, from my wifi?

Comment: How do you connect? VPN? RDP? VPN + RDP?

Comment: did you installed any software on your private box? i'm not familiar with DyKnow, but if you you installed this on your home box, thet it could be possible

Comment: From https://www.dyknow.com/features/: *"MONITOR STUDENT DEVICES
View all student screens in real-time to see student device activity snapshots"*. Thus, likely they can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - software installed on a machine can monitor all activity, regardless of network connection. It likely even works when the computer is offline, storing all the information locally until it's connected to the internet again when it can send its stored info to your school administrators. It won't be able to monitor any other devices on the same network through - if you've connected your school laptop to your home wifi your tablet or phone won't be monitored. While I'm not familiar with the software, stuff I'd assume is monitored and alerted on:

- websites you visit
- installing software
- any attempts to access underlying system resources, such as console commands, attempting to run scripts as an admin, etc
- files downloaded

Keep in mind that while HTTPS blocks someone from sniffing your network stream, it doesn't work on something installed on the device because that sits outside the protected HTTPS tunnel. Anything sent over HTTPS can still be viewed (chat messages on FB, etc).

When using a device that you don't fully own/have admin rights over, it's always wisest to use it as if someone was watching your screen the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

@Buffalo5ix is correct. DyKnow is seems to be working as a keylogger. it will monitor your compuer all the time and send details to school authority. What information it is sending to school authority?, that depends on setting/configuration of DyKnow. 
Details of other devices will not be sent as DyKnow is not installed in other devices.